# How a good data-request question should look

Tags: discussion, data-request

More than half of the questions on OpenData are [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) questions, so I think it is time to think a bit more about:

1. How would the ideal [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) question look like?
2. What are the minimum things that a [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) question must have?

Answer (score 14):

## The ideal data request

1. **Data**: Explain exactly what data you are looking for. Put a Wikipedia link under each ambiguous word or abbreviation, as abbreviations can have a different meaning in different fields.
2. **Context**: What are you actually trying to achieve, what is your final goal that the data will help you get done?
3. **Region**: Not everybody is in the USA. Say what country/region your question applies to, if applicable. Some questions do not need a region, for instance questions about chemistry or astronomy. If you want data that covers the whole globe, say it explicitly as well.
4. **License**: Say what licenses are acceptable, and whether you are ready to invest money on it or not.
5. **Format**: Say what numeric units and data/file format you want, if you have a preference. Say whether screen-scraping answers are acceptable or not.
6. **Authority**: What kind of organization do you want the data to come from? Government-issued data only? Peer-reviewed data only? Is crowdsourced data OK?
7. **Requirements**: List all other requirements you have.
8. **Non-answers**: If you have tried a few obvious candidates before (or while) asking the question but they don't fit, then explain why. For instance, if you are looking for an encyclopedia but Wikipedia is not a valid answer, then explain why. This will provide more clues to what you are looking for.

See [a full example question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/database-of-english-words-difficulty).

## The minimal data request

1. **Data**: Explain exactly what data you are looking for.
2. **Context**: Optional, but it might prevent us from helping you or making the question more useful. Questions with context are also often more understandable.
3. **Region**: Strongly recommended. If not specified, be prepared to accept answers that only apply to Pakistan or Botswana.
4. **License**: Optional, we will assume you want [open](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/whats-your-interpretation-of-the-open-in-open-data) data.
5. **Format**: Optional, but then be prepared to accept answers in esoteric formats.
6. **Authority**: Optional, we will assume that you are ready to accept answers from potentially unreliable sources if no other source seems to exist.
7. **Requirements**: Optional.
8. **Non-answers**: Strongly recommended. At least show that you have searched for a solution and explain what is wrong with the solutions you have found so far.

Anything I forgot?

Comment: I think this is good (and now I understand more about what you're doing on the main site.)  If we're going to lay it out like this, I would also wonder if there's a respectful but decisive way to ask people not to merely post "wishes" -- many of the data requests are for things which will never be open data, or which would require Wikipedia/OSM class efforts to gather.

Comment: @JoeGermuska: I believe that even difficult-to-fulfil data requests are interesting. Imagine that OSM does not exist, and someone asks for it: Thanks to search engines, OpenData will be the gathering point of people looking for this data, and together they might start the collaboration. Quite a few new datasets were actually created as a direct consequence of the question being posted here, and hopefully it is only the beginning :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Sometimes, yes. But I don't think that's the same as saying that all data requests are equally valuable, and I think there's a real problem with having the unanswered question queue cluttered with essentially unanswerable questions. This meta-question is a great start towards giving guidance for asking better questions.

Comment: @JoeGermuska: Look at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com 58% of unanswered question is perfectly livable, the community over there does not consider it as a problem: it is natural that most software just does not exist yet.

Comment: Not looking for the last word, but just because that site exists does not persuade me that ours should work that way. I would find that site unuseful for the same reasons I think that certain kinds of data request questions are needless clutter on the Open Data SE.

Comment: should we make this information available through the FAQ? Would be very useful to point new user to this information before they ask their questions.