# SE URI Shortcuts/Codes?

Tags: discussion, support

The latest edit to the data-request tag swapped out an example URI with a shortened URI, I'm wondering if this information is available and if there is more information like it.
Note: I had to remove `https://` from the full paths to make these viewable.
Example Full URI:
`opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look`
Example Shortened URI:
`opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/284/17438`
I was impressed that this exists, and also that I am learning it from a new user. My question is where is this information available for others to learn?
I'm assuming `q` maps to `questions` and `17438` is the question id that maps to `how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look`.

Comment: Note that the shortened URL for a post is usually taken from the 'share' link, either from the pop-up, or right-clicking the link directly and copying the URL. And the new user isn't actually new to SE, but a highly active user on another SE site :) Though, it's unfortunate that tag excerpt doesn't actually allow link markdown, so it won't be rendered as a clickable link...

Answer (score 1):

About a year ago, I tried to gather some [documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332251/295232) about the various URLs on Stack Exchange.

In your example, `284` is the question ID and `17438` the ID of user who made the edit. You'll get such a link when you click the 'share' button underneath a post. The user ID is important for badges like [Announcer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer).

The reason you can't post the bare URLs is that they are [automatically rendered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108134/295232). Including them as code works, you don't even need to remove the `https://`:

`https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look`