# How to make links in tag descriptions useful?

Tags: discussion, bug

I am fairly new to this site, but a high rep user on some other sites. I want to do things right.

I wanted to use the tag "data-request". This is the tooltip for the tag :

[image: Data Request tooltip]

When I hover the mouse over the link, the mouse turns into a hand and it looks like I can click the link. However, that only selects the tag and makes it a box.

Do we really expect that new users read the tooltip, remember the whole URL and type that URL into a new tab of the browser?

I can, because I know other sites very well, go to https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request and read the tag description without it disappearing. The URL is still not a link there. But at least I can copy the URL into the clipboard and finally go to [How a good data-request question should look](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/284/17438).

My guess is that this is ~10x more than we can expect from a noob or even average user. How can we improve this, so people actually read the guidance?

Comment: Hi Thomas, nice to see a new user around here :) Good question. I find it problematic too, quite unintuitive and clumsy. I'm quite busy these days, but looking at what other SE websites do should be helpful to find an idea of how to treat the problem.